# Create Blade templates using themself

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I creating blade templates by builder. I make .blade file based in json config. To don't do it in fly I'd like use cached templates.

In loop I fun functions which return me pure html. I get this html and set as `@section('content')` in some.blade.php

To make more complicated elements like carousel I use blade. I looks like

```
protected function getCarousel($element)
  {
    if(isset($element->componentData)){
      $delay = (property_exists($element->componentData,'delay')?$element->componentData->delay:5000);
      $navigationType = (property_exists($element->componentData,'navigationType')?$element->componentData->navigationType:'counter');
      $size = (property_exists($element->componentData,'size')?$element->componentData->size:'standard');
      $images = $element->componentData->images;
      $data= ['images'=>$images,'size'=>$size,'navigationType'=>$navigationType,'delay'=>$delay,'attr'=>$this->getAttributesString($element->attr)];
      return view('backend::components.carousel',$data)->render();
    }
  }
```

All works perfect until I need to only one section. But I need to 2 sections:

@content and @javascript

I'd like from my backend::components.carousel file get string like

```
@section('content')
html
@endsection
@section('javascript')
js code
@endsection
```

My environment

- Laravel 5.4
- PHP 5.6

is it possible or I have to don't use blade to make such code?

Thanks in advance for any hints.

Comment: So what is the problem with opening `backend::components.carousel` view and modify it?

Comment: backend::components.carousel is my file. It's no problem. I can set there @section('javascript') but as result I have file html code only not `@section('javascript')code@endsection`

I'd like get blade template from blade template but little different.

I mean that balde result should be other blade template not pure html